# Load Data into Hive on EMR

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

I created a cluster under the EMR service then I connected with Putty. 
In the meantime, I chose 'presto' when building the cluster.

How do I transfer a file from S3 or on my local computer into the hive?

For example, I need to upload the student file but when I run the following code, I naturally get an error. Where do I put the student file?

```
hive > load data local inpath 'student' into table student_nopart;
```

I'm trying to make an example here.
https://github.com/weltond/LearnBasicBigDataTech

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
load data local inpath ...
```

the `local` is meaning the EMR node, not your computer. By using sftp or something, you should upload the file into EMR first and load it.

OR use this.

```
load data inpath 's3://bucket/path/to/file/' into table <tablename>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have data in S3, you can build Hive table on top of the S3 location or alter existing Hive table.

```
ALTER TABLE student SET location='s3://bucket/path/to/folder_with_table_files';
```